# Books to read on ML after ESL (Elements of Statistical Learning)?

Tags: machine-learning, references

I am almost finished reading ESL; Elements of Statistical Learning.
I come from a strong mathematical and statistical background, and that was my first book about Machine Learning.

**What other books would be good to go over now?**

I am aware of books such as:

- Machine Learning: A Bayesian and Optimization Perspective (.Net Developers Series)
- Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop
- Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective, by Murphy

and I have heard they are all good. However I am unsure of the order of reading or if you may; 'double-reading' same stuff (although that would not be a terrible idea as not everything stuck with me from ESL).

Thank you

Comment: Bishop's book is good. It is also better preparation for the Bayesian skew in the ML field, which you won't have gotten from ESL.

Answer (score 3):

You're going in the right way! In my journey towards machine learning, I found **Python Machine Learning** by Sebastian Raschka very helpful for the start. Though I read a lot books then, this one seriously helped me to kick start the journey.

Beside this one, you could check out some more books. [Here](https://www.onlinebooksreview.com/articles/best-machine-learning-books-with-python) is a good list I followed.
Happy Machine Learning.